# Reference two different versions of JQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have two JQuery plugins that I use for one of my MVC 4 sites

- JQuery Validation
- JQGrid

The JQuery Validation plugin is dependent of JQuery version 1.9 while the JQGrid plugin is dependent on JQuery 1.7.

Both these plugins are used in the same view. How do I include both versions?

I read about the Jquery noconflict function, but because I'm not referencing a specific JQuery version directly this does not apply. I also tried to use the JQuery migrate plugin which didn't seem to work.

Any other ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: jQuery also work with JQuery version 1.9

Comment: Check out jQuery's non conflict mode. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: why don't one person google before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reference two different versions of jQuery, as jqGrid works with 1.9.

Source: the [demo examples](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) on their website use jQ1.9, and also a quote from their [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asystem):

> Requirements: 
>   jQuery library, version 1.3 or later.

If you are using an older version of jqGrid than 4.4.4, you may need to upgrade it. This will be a simpler process than running two versions of jQuery.

Comment: @zzlalani I didn't have one, but to prevent confusion I added one :)

Comment: Yes I'm using an older version. Will upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with one version of jquery and simply upgrade your JQGRID version, it has supported 1.9 since January :)

> 12:30 2013-01-30 (GMT) jqGrid 4.4.4 is released. This version add
>   support for jQuery 1.9 and jQuery UI 1.10 For a full list of changes
>   please refer to Change Log

See here for more info http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php there should be no problems upgrading. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I was using an older version, but will upgrade. +1.