# How can i use two different versions of JQUERY library

Tags: jquery

I am using a external Jquery plugin in my project. In plugin they are using jquery-1.3.2.js. For my functionality i am using library jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js.

The problem is that if i am commenting out  jquery-1.3.2, some functionality of Plugin is not working. If i am having both the libraries Jquery on method is not working.

```
// This will not work if we have both the libraries.

$(document.body).on('click', '.productWrap', function(){
    alert ("reaching here");
});
```

I don't have any idea what functionality of plugin is using jQuery-1.3.2.

How to fix this issue, so that plugin and on method both can work perfectly, without any major changes in the code.

Comment: You really shouldn't use two versions of jQuery together. Find newer version of the plugin, or a different plugin that is using newer jQuery.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: you are wrong, you can use multiple jQuery versions...

Comment: @Legionar OK, after some research I came to conclusion it's just like using two different libraries. Opinion retracted. :)

Comment: And where is the accepted answer???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible; just use `$.noConflict(true);`:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.10.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

**Example:**

Instead of

`$('#selector').function();`

you'd do

`jQuery_1_3_2('#selector').function();`

or

`jQuery_1_10_2('#selector').function();`.

Comment: Thanks for response. In fact i knew this answer. But For this i need to make changes in both Plugin and my code. Every selector i need to replace with proper version of library. Also i should be knowing where to use jQuery_1_3_2 and where to use jQuery_1_10_2. Is there any way to avoid this??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal: No, just alias it. `(function($) { /*your code here*/ }(jquery_x_x_x));`

Comment: Interesting, but [very similar answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1sATW.png) to [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450669/447356) has been downvoted. Oh well!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: What??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery.noConflict - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Include your 1.3.2 version of jQuery.

Then include 1.10.2 version of jQuery.

Then do,

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Hereafter, whereever you use $ in your script, you have to use j.
Ex: $("#id1") => j("#id1")